# Multiple table Join using LINQ returning no values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have three tables as bellow:

```
Table A
Id
Divi_code
Unit_code 
Other column


Table B
Divi_code
Divi_name

Table c
Unit_code
Unit_name
```

I have a list generated from table A using some where condition, the list item may or may not have divi_code/unit_code values. I now need to find the divi_name/unit_name if the list contains any value for divi_code/unit_code. I'm doing this coz I don't want to send divi/unit code to the UI, I want send the names.

I tried to join these table like bellow:

```
var list = (from s in DataContext.HRM_HLDY_SPCL_FOR.AsEnumerable()
                    where s.HLDY_DATE == Convert.ToDateTime(Date)

                    join dv in DataContext.HRM_DIVISION on s.DIVI_CODE equals dv.DIVI_CODE

                    join un in DataContext.HRM_UNIT on s.UNIT_CODE equals un.UNIT_CODE

                    select new HRM_HLDY_SPCL_FORModel { HLDY_SPCL_SLNO = (s.HLDY_SPCL_SLNO).ToString(), DIVI_NAME= dv.DIVI_NAME, UNIT_NAME= un.UNIT_NAME, ActiveStatus= s.ACTIVE_STATUS, HLDY_SPCL_REM= s.HLDY_SPCL_REM}).ToList();
```

My query only facing those data which have both divi_code & unit_code. I would like to have all the data in my list even if it don't have divi_code/unit_code. In that case null for divi_name/unit_name would be good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are describing a `left join` in linq. There are diffrent ways to accomplish that. I like this way the most. It is clear that it is a left join:

```
var list = (from s in DataContext.HRM_HLDY_SPCL_FOR.AsEnumerable()

                from dv in DataContext.HRM_DIVISION
                    .Where(d=>d.DIVI_CODE==s.DIVI_CODE).DefaultIfEmpty()

                from un in DataContext.HRM_UNIT 
                    .Where(u=>u.UNIT_CODE== s.UNIT_CODE).DefaultIfEmpty()
                where s.HLDY_DATE == Convert.ToDateTime(Date)
                select new HRM_HLDY_SPCL_FORModel 
                { 
                    HLDY_SPCL_SLNO = (s.HLDY_SPCL_SLNO).ToString(), 
                    DIVI_NAME= (dv==null?null:dv.DIVI_NAME), 
                    UNIT_NAME= (un==null?null:un.UNIT_NAME), 
                    ActiveStatus= s.ACTIVE_STATUS, 
                    HLDY_SPCL_REM= s.HLDY_SPCL_REM
                }
                ).ToList();
```

Comment: I was quick to think it would work, but now I tried this & getting error when it don't a divi_code/unit_code. the error says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." :(

Comment: Hi, Im trying to do it again, this time I have two condition to check in the where clause & getting the null reference error. isn't it possible to check tow condition?

Comment: I'm trying something like this,  var EducationDetails = (from e in DataContext.HRM_EMP_EDUCATION.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.EMP_CODE == Employee_Code)
                                    from ex in DataContext.HRM_EDUCATION.Where(x => x.EDU_TYPE == "EXAM" && x.EDU_CODE == e.EXAM_CODE).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                    select new HRM_EMP_EDUCATIONModel
                                    {
                                        EXAM_NAME= ex.EDU_NAME==null? "N/A":ex.EDU_NAME
                                    }).ToList();