# LINQ JOIN Child Collection

Tags: linq, join, parent-child

I have a `meetingRepository` class that returns IEnumerable and an `attendeeRepository` class that returns `IEnumerable<Attendee>`

```
public class meetingRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Meeting> GetAll()
    {
        //return all Meetings
    }
}

public class attendeeRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Attendee>GetAll()
    {
        //return all Attendees
    }
}


public class Meeting
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }
}

public class Attendee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MeetingId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get set;}
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

Im struggling to come up with the link statement that will join my `IEnumerable<Meeting>` object with my `IEnumerable<Attendee>` joining each `Attendee` in the `Attendees` property of the `Meeting` to its related `Attendee` object based on the `Attendee.Id`

Help appreciated

**Edit**

@Thomas the meetingRepository I have available does not load the Attendees, it is just a full list of all Meetings (I editted to include the Id property).
So, to clarify, my meetingRepository returns an IEnumerable of a partial Meeting object (no attendees)

```
Id
Date
Duration
FilePath
```

and my attendeeRepository returns an IEnumerable of participants (editted to include MeetingId

```
Id
MeetingId
Name
Role
```

**Edit**

I came up with the folowing that seems to work fine

```
var meetingsFull = from m in meetings
                    join a in attendees
                    on m.Id equals a.MeetingId into ma
                    select new Meeting
                    {
                        Id=pc.Id, 
                        Date=pc.Date, 
                        Duration=pc.Duration, 
                        FilePath=pc.FilePath, 
                        Attendees=ma
                    };
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... If the meeting already has the attendees, you don't need to use the attendee repository for this query. What result do you expect?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989195/multiple-table-join-using-linq-returning-no-values

Answer (score 0):

```
var attendees = attendeeRepository.GetAll();

foreach(var meeting in meetingRepository.GetAll())
{ 
    meeting.Attendees = attendees.Where(at=>at.MeetingId == meeting.Id);
}
```

This should do it. After these assignments your all meetings now have the attendees lists ready in them.

Comment: Thanks.  This was the way that I was doing it but though there must be another way using a LINQ join.  I came up with the code block that I put in my latest edit